# atom package html div.row>div.columns.small-12.medium-4*3

Tags: html, atom-editor

I'm looking for a atom package for using html like

```
div.row>div.columns.small-12.medium-4*3
```

to create your code !
I can't find it, and i have absolutely no idea about the name of it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the package, for the best editor <3

https://atom.io/packages/emmet